# Method undefined (type has no method)

Tags: class, oop, go, types

If I try a file like this:

```
package main
import "time"
type Alpha time.Time
func main() {
   o := Alpha.Now()
   n := o.Unix()
   println(n)
}
```

I get this result:

```
Alpha.Now undefined (type Alpha has no method Now)
```

However it works with other languages. For example PHP:

```php
<?php
class Alpha extends DateTime {}
$o = new Alpha;
$n = $o->getTimestamp();
var_dump($n);
```

It is possible with Go, to create a new type that has access to the methods of
another type?

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#Is_Go_an_object-oriented_language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `time.Now()` is just a package-level function, not a method of any type. Thus, the proper way to invoke it would look like `smth := time.Time()`, not `smth := time.Time.Now()`.

We can take a closer look at the function. It's defined in package [time](https://golang.org/src/time/time.go) and currently implemented as follows:

```
func Now() Time {
    sec, nsec, mono := now()
    mono -= startNano
    sec += unixToInternal - minWall
    if uint64(sec)>>33 != 0 {
        return Time{uint64(nsec), sec + minWall, Local}
    }
    return Time{hasMonotonic | uint64(sec)<<nsecShift | uint64(nsec), mono, Local}
}
```

As you can see, it returns an object of type `time.Time`. Which then can be used for the consequent `.Unix()` method call:

```
func (t Time) Unix() int64 {
    return t.unixSec()
}
```

In case of `Unix()` it's a true method with the receiver of type `time.Time`.

For the extension part of your question, you can use the following trick:

```
package main
import "time"

type Alpha struct {
  time.Time
}

func main() {
   o := time.Now()
   a := Alpha { o }
   n := a.Unix()
   println(n)
}
```

Go doesn't provide any model of inheritance. However, its composition capabilities are very powerful. The code from the snippet above basically creates a new struct type `Alpha` with an anonymous attribute of type `time.Time`. However, due to the fact that the explicit name of this attribute is skipped, we can access methods of a contained `time.Time` instance right through the parent structure. The technique is called [Embedding](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding).

Comment: Great example +1. A simpler version of this is here https://play.golang.org/p/WoqmXoWAY-u.